# SQL query works well but not the function made from it

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am trying to make a function that returns flight duration.

It works well with a simple query but when I try with the function it return 0...

This returns 1:00

```
declare @FlightId int,
        @Departure datetime,
        @Arrival datetime,
        @duration varchar

set @FlightId = (select FlightId from Flight where FlightNumber = 'ZZZ')
set @Departure = (select min(Departure) from Step where FlightId = @FlightId )
set @Arrival = (select max(Arrival) from Step where FlightId = @FlightId )

select CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @Departure, @Arrival), 0), 114)
```

and this is the function that returns 0

```
alter function FlightDuration
    (@FlightNumber varchar(50)) 
returns varchar
as 
begin
    declare @FlightId int,
            @Departure datetime,
            @Arrival datetime,
            @duration varchar

    set @FlightId = (select FlightId from Flight where FlightNumber = @FlightNumber)
    set @Departure = (select min(Departure) from Step where FlightId = @FlightId )
    set @Arrival = (select max(Arrival) from Step where FlightId = @FlightId )

    set @duration = CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @Departure, @Arrival), 0), 114)

    return @duration
end
```

I call it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.FlightDuration ('ZZZ')
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could easily be the length attribute on `varchar`.  Without a length, SQL Server defaults to a length of "1".

So, try declaring the function as:

```
alter function FlightDuration (
    @FlightNumber varchar(50)
) returns varchar(12)
begin
    . . .
end;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I aslo had to declare the variable like this @duration varchar(12) and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the flight 'ZZZ' does not exists. In the first case, `@FlightId` might have been set by a previous query. To check if the query is successful do something like this:

```
SET @FlightId = NULL;
SELECT @FlightId = FlightId FROM Flight WHERE ...
IF @FlightId IS NULL
  SET @duration = 'N/A'
ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT @Departure = min(Departure), @Arrival = max(Arrival) FROM Step WHERE FlightId = @FlightId;
  SET @duration = CONVERT...
END
```